# Reading Kafka Headers but not the payload

Tags: apache-kafka

I am consuming from a Kafka topic where many massages (like 80k per minutes) are produced, out of which I am interested only in 1k messages.

What I was planning to do is using kafka headers and ignore the message with header that I am not interested in.

However in my consumer code, when I poll as below

`ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));`

and then loop through it

`records.forEach(record -> { Headers headers = record.headers();`

the poll itself will pull the message key, payload, header everything and consume consumer application server memory (as part of the records object).

So by checking header and ignoring I will only be able to minimize the processing time /memory by avoiding parsing / DTOing the payload, however is there a way I can overall avoid pulling the message body and only read header and seek to next offset until I get the header that I am interested in and then pull the message payload. That would be most optimum from the consumer application resource utilization perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible; the Kafka consumer protocol will always poll a batch of whole records. You can use ByteArrayDeserializer on the consumer config to not *deserialize* key/values, but the memory allocation for the records themselves will always be there